# jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: user not allowed to log on to this computer

Tags: java, jcifs

Trying to read a file over a Windows in Java using jCIFS library in java.

This section of code was working perfectly fine when the user had the “Logon locally” rights enabled in Windows. However when we implemented the password non-expiry property our server team has disabled the “Logon locally” rights for the user.

Now, when we browsed the path -   manually, we are able to access it without any issue.
When application tries to access the path getting below error at app server:

> FATAL - jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: user not allowed to log on to this computer.
>
> FATAL - Error msg: Logon failure: user not allowed to log on to this computer.

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, "domain\\"+this.userName, this.password);
String fileName = "";
String filePath = "";
while (result1.next()) {
    for(int i=1; i<=columnsNumber1; i++) {
        String name = rsmd1.getColumnName(i);
        if(name.equals("FILE_PATH")) {
        filePath = result1.getString(i);
        } else if (name.equals("PDF_FILE_NAME")) {
        fileName = result1.getString(i);
        }
    }
}
String newFilePath = filePath.replace('\\', '/');
String path = "smb:"+newFilePath+"/Stored/"+fileName;
SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
try (SmbFileInputStream in = new SmbFileInputStream(sFile)) {
    int bytesRead = 0;
    do {
        bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
    } 
    while (bytesRead > 0);
}
byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(buffer);
```

Do we have to set particular property for NtlmPasswordAuthentication authentication in this case?
Please do help, got stuck here

Answer (score 0):

I found its solution. Posting it here if it can help others.
Adding two config properties helped - "jcifs.netbios.hostname" and "jcifs.netbios.wins"

```
Config.setProperty("jcifs.netbios.hostname", Messages.getString("Constants.serverHostName"));
Config.setProperty("jcifs.netbios.wins", Messages.getString("Constants.serverHostName"));
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, "edelcap\\"+this.reportUserName, this.reportPassword);
```